# BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate : No default constructor found;

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am experimenting with Spring 5, when I run the Test Application, it throws this exception. I understand that we need a zero-argument constructor if we are using @Autowired for Fields and Setter Methods since the bean is first instantiated with a zero-argument constructor and then dependant beans are injected. But why do we need a zero-argument constructor if the constructor is @Autowired since this constructor would be used for instantiating the bean?

```
is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.spring.hello.Student]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.spring.hello.Student.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
```

**Student.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Student {
    
    private PersonalInfo pI;
    
    @Autowired
    public Student (PersonalInfo pI) {
        this.pI = pI;
    }
    
}
```

**PersonalInfo.java**

```
@Component
public class PersonalInfo {
    
    String name;
    
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private PersonalInfo() {
        System.out.println("constructor...");
    }
    
    public String printHello() {
        return "PersonalInfo...";
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.spring.hello.Student;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("/com/spring/resources/applicationContext.xml");
        Student bean = (Student) context.getBean("student");
        System.out.println(bean);
        
        
    }

}
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="student" class="com.spring.hello.Student">
        <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
    </bean>
    <bean id="personalInfo" class="com.spring.hello.personalInfo">
        <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**EDIT**

After updating the Test class, I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'student' available.
```

Comment: Can you share your `applicationContext.xml`? As a sidenote; your domain objects should not be beans.

Comment: Agreed. It's just for understanding :) Updated

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are mixing annotation configuration with XML configuration.
Because you create an instance of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, only what is in the XML will be taken as configuration and your `@Autowired` annotation gets ignored.

To fix the error with xml you need to add the bean injection in the xml definition:

```xml
    <bean id="student" class="com.spring.hello.Student">
        <constructor-arg ref="personalInfo" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="personalInfo" class="com.spring.hello.personalInfo"></bean>
```

If you want to use annotation config instead, you can create an instance of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instead. You then still need to annotate student and personalInfo with `@Component` so Spring can find them as beans when scanning the provided package.

```java
@Component
public class PersonalInfo {
  ...
}

@Component
public class Student{
   ...
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.scan("com.spring.hello");
    ctx.refresh();
}
```

Comment: I have updated it. But this time, I am getting "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'student' available" exception.

Comment: @skgv `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("/com/spring/resources/applicationContext.xml")` is wrong. Just copy/paste the initialization from my post.